# Rotation matrix mapping one vector to another

Tags: matrices, 3d, rotations, transformation

In one of the online lectures, the instructor mentioned about the rotation matrix that maps a vector $g$ to another vector $e$ (assuming unit vectors) and it's written as:

$R = I_{3\times3} + 2eg^T + \frac{1}{1 + e^Tg}(e + g)(e + g)^T$

This looks very similar to some form of Rodrigues' rotation formula, but I'm struggling to figure out how to derive the above rotation formula from Rodrigues' formula, e.g., what's the rotation axis and the angle. Any hint/explanation with simple algebra/geometric intuition would be appreciated!

Comment: The rotation axis has the same direction as the cross product $e \times g$.

Comment: @angryavian Can you explain more about how the sum of the two vectors such as $e + g$ pops out if we use $e \times g$ as the rotation axis? I'm having trouble linking this with the skew-symmetric matrix in Rodrigues' formula...

Comment: Suppose $e = g$ , then $R$ should be equal to the identify matrix.  But using the formula you gave, it is not.  So the formula cannot be right.